# how to set a button layout_marginTop/layout_marginBottom in runtime?

Tags: android, button, android-widget, runtime

I am using a relative layout with 4 buttons (in the center, one below the other).
My problem is to adjust the gap between all buttons so it will be the same between all buttons.

I want to do it dynamically according to the height of the screen (i use Display class to get the actual height).

what is the best way to do it?

Thanks,
Amigal

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can do this via modifying the LayoutParams of your View

```
Button b;// your button
RelativeLayout.LayoutParams lp=(RelativeLayout.LayoutParams)b.getLayoutParams();
lp.leftMargin=10;//your left margin here
lp.topMargin=10;//your top margin here and do this for other 2 margins if you need to
```

sometimes you need to call

```
b.setLayoutParams(lp);
```

to have the changes applied

also i dont know how you get the screen dimensions, but this works at every API:

```
DisplayMetrics metrics = new DisplayMetrics();
getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay().getMetrics(metrics);
```